# How do I print items in a dictionary from highest value to lowest value using Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to do something like the following but do not know how to make it compatible with the HTML that I've written for my program.

```
{% for u in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True) %}
    {{ u|safe }}<br>
    Priority level <b>{{ dictionary[u] }}</b><br>
    ---<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not opposed to doing it in the views.py file either. Ideally I'd like to only show the top 20 or so results as well.

Comment: how are you getting the dictionary? can you show the views? is the dictionary coming from database?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show the whole code. Check out http://sigsecure.ngrok.io if you want to see what I'm trying to do. Here is the rendering- `return render(request, 'patrec.html', {'siglist':sorted(siglist.iteritems()), 'best_match':best_match,})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything from everywhere to no avail. I came up with the following-

```
sort = []
for u in sorted(siglist, key=siglist.get, reverse=True)[:25]:
    sort.append([u, str(siglist[u])])

return render(request, 'patrec.html', {
    'siglist': sort, 
    'best_match': best_match,
})
```

And then put the following in the HTML-

```
{% for u in siglist %}
    {{ u.0 }}<br>
    {{ u.1 }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort in the view, as you are doing, and also reverse the order and limit to 20:

```
return render(request, 'patrec.html', {
    'siglist': sorted(siglist.iteritems(), reverse=True)[:20], 
    'best_match': best_match,
})
```

And then access the sorted items in the template:

```
{% for tup in siglist %}
    <p> Key is {{ tup[0] }} </p>
    <p> Value is {{ tup[1] }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try inbuilt dictsort to sort your dictionary https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort